# how can I install v.6.x of socket.io by NPM now?

Tags: socket.io, npm

I got lots of problem to work on v.7.x,but now I have to move my
 project to a new server.so,I have to install socket.io again.
 but,when I used "npm install socket.io" I got the last version.My
 project using v.6.x,now I really cant install v.7.x,so,how can I
 install v.6.x by NPM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you can do it by

You can see listing by

```
npm ls socket.io

sudo npm install socket.io@0.6
```